# Converting WebBrowser.Document To A Bitmap?

Tags: c#, browser, drawtobitmap

Is it possible to draw a WebBrowser.Document to a Bitmap?  Basically taking a screenshot of a WebBrowser control (note, this is with a WebBrowser that doesn't live on a form, but just in code).

```
WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
w.Document = "<b>Hello</b> world.";
w.Document.DrawToBitmap ???
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer from @webspy should be accepted as a better answer. The reasons for this are that it works when the browser is not visible on the screen (it could even be outside the bounds of the screen).

Comment: A related q/a: [How to fix a opacity bug with DrawToBitmap on WebBrowser Control?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21697048/1768303)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.bryancook.net/2006/03/screen-capture-for-invisible-windows.html

and here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/screen_capturing.aspx

I believe you should get the handle of your WebBrowser control and save it's content as image like suggested in those links.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "get the handle of your WebBrowser control"? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 28):

I use the following code to capture a screenshot of a web page loaded in a WebBrowser control:

```
class NativeMethods
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("0000010D-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IViewObject
    {
        void Draw([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwAspect, int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, [In] IntPtr ptd, IntPtr hdcTargetDev, IntPtr hdcDraw, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref RECT lprcBounds, [In] IntPtr lprcWBounds, IntPtr pfnContinue, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwContinue);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    public static void GetImage(object obj, Image destination, Color backgroundColor)
    {
        using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destination))
        {
            IntPtr deviceContextHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            RECT rectangle = new RECT();

            rectangle.Right = destination.Width;
            rectangle.Bottom = destination.Height;

            graphics.Clear(backgroundColor);

            try
            {
                deviceContextHandle = graphics.GetHdc();

                IViewObject viewObject = obj as IViewObject;
                viewObject.Draw(1, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, deviceContextHandle, ref rectangle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                if(deviceContextHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    graphics.ReleaseHdc(deviceContextHandle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
NativeMethods.GetImage(webBrowser.ActiveXInstance, screenshot, Color.White);
```

Comment: Thank you for this one, works really well. But i have a bit weird problem, when i take the render, it seems like the image is streched and zoomed (the picture box itself does not do this). Do you have any idea what might be causing this.

Comment: The answer is pretty simple though - resize the webbrowser with the Width/Height methods of WebBrowser class. Thank you webspy for this nifty piece of code.

Comment: That's great. You saved hours of my work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void HTMLScreenShot()
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
        wb.Size = new Size(800, 600);

        // Add html as string
        wb.Navigate("about:blank");
        wb.Document.Write("<b>Hellow World!</b>");
        // Add html from website
        // wb.Navigate("http://myurl.com");

    }

    void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;

        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height))
        {
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), wb.Size);
            wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, bounds);
            bitmap.Save("C:\WebsiteScreenshot.png");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//
//   If you want to take a snap from existing webBrowser Control
//

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using (FileDialog fd = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            fd.Filter = "Image (*.png)|*.png";
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                new WebPageSnap(webBrowser1.Url.ToString(), fd.FileName);
                //might take 3 or 4 seconds to save cauz it has to load again.
            }
        }
    }


//
//   Or if you want to take a snap without showing up
//


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using (FileDialog fd = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            fd.Filter = "Image (*.png)|*.png";
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string url = "http://www.google.com";
                // or 
                url = textBox1.Text;
                new WebPageSnap(url, fd.FileName);                }
        }
    }

    class WebPageSnap
    {
        WebBrowser wb;
        string outFile;

        public WebPageSnap(string url, string outputFile)
        {
            wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.ProgressChanged += wb_ProgressChanged;
            outFile = outputFile;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            wb.Navigate(url);
        }

        void wb_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CurrentProgress == e.MaximumProgress)
            {
                wb.ProgressChanged -= wb_ProgressChanged;
                try
                {
                    int scrollWidth = 0;
                    int scrollHeight = 0;

                    scrollHeight = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
                    scrollWidth = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
                    wb.Size = new Size(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);


                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
                    for (int Xcount = 0; Xcount < bitmap.Width; Xcount++)
                        for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < bitmap.Height; Ycount++)
                            bitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, Color.Black);
                    wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
                    bitmap.Save(outFile, ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

    }
```