# How to remove an HTML element programatically from web browser control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I use a web browser control and the document is loaded with an HTML page. I want to remove an element programmatically form the document.

Can any one guide me how can I remove any element by ID or name attribute?

Comment: remove only. i know hide is easy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006825/converting-webbrowser-document-to-a-bitmap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `Microsoft.mshtml` library. I accomplished it using the power of the `dynamic` datatype:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.ToString() == "https://www.google.com/")
    {
        dynamic htmldoc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as dynamic;
        dynamic node = htmldoc.getElementById("lga") as dynamic;
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("element").OuterHtml = "";
```

Comment: Yes, this works, is simpler than Hanlet's solution and also has the advantage of not having to use `dynamic`.

Comment: not all elements can be removed by setting OuterHTML. When trying to do that for a `TBODY` tag for example, you get `System.NotSupportedException: 'Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement.'` probably because you cannot remove tags that are a structural part of an HTML element. In this case you have to go up and remove the parent.

Answer (score 3):

It is the VB.Net version. I tried removing `MsHTML`. but referencing that library has its own problem. The below is not a direct answer but can be workaround to stop loading external resources using `iframes`.

```
 For Each FrameElement As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")
 Debug.Print(FrameElement.OuterHtml)
 FrameElement.OuterHtml = Nothing
 Next
```

Answer (score 1):

OuterHtml Can not be modified!

This code removes Css Links from WebPage:

```html
 Sub RemoveStylesheet()
        Dim styles As HTMLStyleSheetsCollection = WB.Document.DomDocument.styleSheets
1:
        If styles.length > 0 Then
            For Each stl As Object In WB.Document.DomDocument.styleSheets
                '     stl.removeImport(0)
                If stl Is Nothing Then Continue For
                Dim st As IHTMLElement = stl.owningElement
                '  st.href = ""
                '   MsgBox(st.tagName)
                st.parentElement.removeChild(st)
            Next
            GoTo 1
        End If

     
    End Sub
```

Comment: OuterHtml didn't work for me, but parent.InnerHtml = "" works.

Comment: @Dave5709 but isn't very appropriate because that will wipe the siblings as well

Comment: @Epirocks In my use case the parent only had 1 child, but that's a good point